# How to extract a href from a given div?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I have the following piece of web page's HTML code:

```
<div class="align-center">
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block w-condition-invisible">
  <img src="https://global.com/slack-symbol.png" alt="Slack link">
</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://twitter.com/abc" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
  <img src="https://global.com/twitter.png" width="16" alt="Twitter link">
</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://t.me/abc" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
  <img src="https://global.com/telegram.png" alt="Telegram link">
</a>
</div>
```

Also, I have the list of link names as follows:

```
links_dict = {}
links = ["Slack","Twitter","Telegram"]
```

I want to extract `href` values for each corresponding link. If there is no `href` (see Slack in the sample code above), it means that there is no link.

The expected output is the following:

```
"Slack" -> "None"
"Twitter" -> "https://twitter.com/abc"
"Telegram" -> "https://t.me/abc"
```

I cannot access `a href` just by `a`, because there are many other `div` elements with other `a`.

I would like to use `BeautifulSoap` or `Selenium` with `PhantomJS`. This is what I tried:

**BeautifulSoap:**

```
res = requests.get("https://myurl.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all(class_="align-center")
for tag in tags:
    print tag.text.strip()
```

**Selenium:**

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://mytest.com")

tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("align-center")

for tag in tags:
    tag.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
    url = driver.current_url
    print(url)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the below solutions? What's your feedback?

Comment: @Shahin: I found the solution myself. Also, I do not understand why my question is downvoted. Please upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below script. It will fetch you the desired results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<div class="align-center">
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block w-condition-invisible">
  <img src="https://global.com/slack-symbol.png" alt="Slack link">
</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://twitter.com/abc" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
  <img src="https://global.com/twitter.png" width="16" alt="Twitter link">
</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://t.me/abc" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
  <img src="https://global.com/telegram.png" alt="Telegram link">
</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html5lib")
links = {item.get("alt").split(" ")[0]:link.get('href') for item,link in zip(soup.select(".align-center a img"),soup.select(".align-center a"))}
print(links)
```

Output:

```
{'Slack': None, 'Telegram': 'https://t.me/abc', 'Twitter': 'https://twitter.com/abc'}
```

Or you can do the same in slightly different way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html5lib")
for item in soup.select(".align-center a img"):
    title = item.get("alt").split(" ")[0]
    link = item.findParent().get('href')
    print(title,link)
```

Output:

```
Slack None
Twitter https://twitter.com/abc
Telegram https://t.me/abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your idea using BeatifulSoup, you could find all the `img` links from each tag, and then check if the link contains the correct `alt` pattern.

If the pattern is correct, get the parent's link.

```
import re

...

links = []
tags = soup.find_all(class_="align-center")
for tag in tags:
    # For each tag, get all the images
    for img in tag.find_all('img'):
        # Ensure the img has the correct `alt` pattern
        if re.match('(Twitter|Slack|Telegram) link', img.attrs.get('alt')):
            # Store the link found.
            links.append(img.findParent().attrs.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to extract the `href` values for each corresponding `alt` attribute in the child node, you can use **`Selenium`** as per the following code block :

```
tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='align-center']/a/img")
my_alt = []
my_href= []
for tag in tags:
    alt_text = tag.getAttribute("alt")
    my_alt.append(alt_text)
    my_href.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='align-center']/a/img[.='" + alt_text + "']//preceding::a[1]").getAttribute("href"))
for alt, href in zip(my_alt, my_href):
    print(alt, href)
```